# How to use the same button to generate and remove specific text label from Tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I just started to learn Tkinter. Going through  a beginner project I tripped over this situation where I have to use the same button to generate a string and replace it with a new one as the new ones are overlapping the old ones. Here're the code segments:

```
def ranQ():

    if root.count < len(root.LoQ):
        tx=canv.create_text(400, 50, text=root.LoQ[root.count], font=('Jokerman', 15), fill="Purple")
        root.count += 1

    else:
        # l2 = Label(root, text="End of 7 questions! Click to generate again!", fg= "white", bg ="red")
        # l2.pack()
        canv.create_text(400, 450, text="End of 7 questions! Click to generate again!", font=('Jokerman', 10), fill="Purple")
        root.count=0

        random.shuffle(root.LoQ)

# defining background image
im = PhotoImage(file="{path}")

# Creating a canvas

canv = Canvas(root, width =800, height=500)
canv.pack(fill ="both", expand= True)

# Putting the image in canvas

canv.create_image(0,0, image=im, anchor='nw')

# adding a text label

canv.create_text(400,450,text ="7 Random Questions!", font=('Jokerman',50), fill="black")
canv.create_text(404,454,text ="7 Random Questions!", font=('Jokerman',50), fill="purple")

# adding the generate button
btn_g = Button(root, text='Press to generate a random question'.upper(),font=('Jokerman',10), padx=60, pady=20, fg="white", bg='Red',
                  command=ranQ)
b_window = canv.create_window(220,225,anchor="nw", window= btn_g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

def callback():
    new_text = randint(0, 100)
    # Reconfigure the text
    canvas.itemconfig(text_id, text=new_text)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack()

# Save the text id that the canvas gives us
text_id = canvas.create_text(100, 100, text="")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=callback)
button.pack(fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

Basically you reconfigure the text. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15193471/11106801)